# Use Value of a Column into another Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the values:

```
id      |   cat    |    AttribGroup  |  AttribID   |   Value
1            1           test             001          beautiful
1            1           test             002          handsome
```

Now what I what I want to happen is:

```
id      |   cat    |    test_001     |  test_002  
1            1         beautiful        handsome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f09dc/32)

It consists of a PIVOT and then join the results to the initial table.

Since i guess that your values are not going to be just test_001 and test_002 you are going to need some dynamic SQL in order to define the columns.

The code :

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + AttribGroup + '_' + AttribID +']'
            FROM Table1 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET @query = 
';WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT    * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT    AttribGroup + ''_'' + AttribID  AS ColName, 
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR,id)+''_''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,cat) AS idcat, 
                  Value
        FROM      Table1
    ) p
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX    (Value)
        FOR    ColName IN (' + @cols + ')
    )   AS pvt
)

SELECT    t.id,
          t.cat,
          m.* 
FROM      MyCTE m
          JOIN 
          (
              SELECT    id,
                        cat,
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR,id)+''_''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,cat) as idcat
              FROM      Table1
              GROUP BY  id,
                        cat
          ) t
              ON m.idcat = t.idcat'


EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Hi I wanted to upvote but it says "Upvote required 15 reputation." Sorry I'm a newbie here. I actually wanted to post again the sql I made using your code but I don't know how. I am going to post new question in connection to this question.

Comment: Haha! I finally saw how to accept your answer. Uhm, yes? here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505958/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error